# Shop arrivals probability in a given time assuming Poisson process

Tags: probability, poisson-process

Assume that customers arrive to a shop according to a Poisson process with intensity 2 customers/minute. Let $X(t)$ be the number of customers arriving in a time intervall [0,t].

a) Calculate P$(X(3) = 4)$

I figured I would use the gamma distribution and use $x = 3$.

$$\Gamma(4, 2) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\frac{(\lambda x)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} = 72e^{-6} \approx 0.18$$

However the key says the answer is approximately $0.13$.

Comment: Well if $S_n$ is the arrival time of the $n$:th costumer and $T_n$ are independent and identical exponential random variables with $\lambda = 2$ denoting the time between arrivals for customer $n-1$ and $n$. Then $S_n = \sum^n_{i=1} T_i$ and this is how I thought we defined a gamma distribution?

Comment: Ah, but we are *not* measuring interarrival times, @Mevve .  The random variables in question are *counts of arrivals* within time intervals, which are Poisson distributed (since this is a Poisson process).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you use a *gamma* distribution?

It is a **Poisson** process.   Use a Poisson distribution.

$$X(t)\sim\mathcal{Pois}(2t)\quad\iff\quad\mathsf P(X(t){=}k)=\dfrac{(2t)^k\mathrm e^{-2t}}{k!}\cdot\mathbf 1_{k\in\Bbb N_0}$$

Comment: Thanks, if you got time could you also tell me why my reasoning in my comment above is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

**Reply to OP's query** following Graham Kemp's answer (too long for a comment).

There's nothing wrong with the reasoning in your comment per se, except that it's not relevant for the problem you were asked to solve. Your $\ S_n\ $ is the time of the arrival of the $\ n$-th customer. So the *cumulative distribution* function of your $\ \Gamma(4,2)$-distributed $\ S_4\ $, evaluated at $\ x=3\ $, will tell you the probability that the $4$-th arrival will occur within $3$ minutes. While this is the same as the probability of *at least* $4$ arrivals occurring during $3$ minutes, what you were asked to find is the probability that that the number of customers arriving in the interval $\ [0,3]\ $ is *exactly* $4$, which will obviously be smaller.

Also, you appear to have plugged the $\ x=3\ $ into the *density function* of $\ S_4\ $ rather than its cumulative distribution function, and that won't even give you the correct probability for the $4$-th arrival occurring within $3$ minutes.

Comment: Ahh i see, thank you for your answer.